# Tmux linux keybindings like S-C-E not working

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, xfce

I am trying to create **S-C-E** shortcut in my **~/.tmux.conf**

I have succeeded with staff like:

```
bind -n ^e split-window -h
bind -n C-e split-window -h
```

### #

But none of the following seems to work:

```
bind -n S-C-e split-window -h
bind -n S-C-E split-window -h
bind -n S-^e split-window -h
bind -n S-^E split-window -h
bind -n S^e split-window -h
bind -n S^E split-window -h
```

### #

Surprisingly even this works:

```
bind -n S-C-Left split-window -h
bind -n S-C-Right split-window -h
```

### #

But this doesn't: :(

```
bind -n S-C-Up split-window -h
bind -n S-C-Down split-window -h
```

### #

How can I create S-C-#character-like shortcut in tmux?

I am using: 
**tmux 2.0** 

xfce4-terminal 0.6.2 (Xfce 4.10) 
Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that those keybindings are not captured by your desktop environment. Look into `xfce4-keyboard-settings` and `xfwm4-settings` for a list of shortcuts.